# ASP.NET: Div event click fail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to call the vb method by clicking on the div but i get that the method is not defined.

My Code:

```
<div id="Div1" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" runat="server" onclick="prueba2()" >
</div>

<script type="text/VB" runat="server">  
    Sub prueba2()
      MsgBox("seee")
    End Sub
</script>
```

**Debug: Uncaught ReferenceError: prueba2 is not defined**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the `onclick` is for javascript:

```
<div id="Div1" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" runat="server" onclick="prueba2()" ></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function prueba2() {
        //do something
    }
</script>
```

Note, for ASP.NET controls, this is not the same. They will have `OnClick` for the code behind function and `OnClientClick` for the client-side javascript function:

```
<asp:Button ID="_someButton" OnClick="VBFunction" Text="Some Text" OnClientClick="prueba2()" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Hi, i replaced the div for asp button but i still get "Uncaught ReferenceError: msg2 is not defined "

Comment: @Fakedo0r if you are changing your code, you need to update your question. My example wasn't to say that you should replace your `div` with a `button`, it was to show that `OnClick` for an ASP control is different than the `onclick` of your `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change your onclick to a javascript that will submit the form using a button.

```
__doPostBack('btnTemp', '');
```

Where btnTemp is a button.

You can find a great example here: [Adding OnClick event to ASP.NET control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893409/adding-onclick-event-to-asp-net-control)